# Spark sortBy : is the order preserved when writing?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have in Scala/Spark :

```
  myDataframe
   .orderBy("date")
   .write
   .csv(...)
```

The generated CSV are :

```
part-00000-xxx.csv
part-00001-xxx.csv
part-00002-xxx.csv
```

**Questions :**

1. Do you know if after running the previous code, the "date" order will be guarantee to be preserved inside a single file ?
2. It is also true between files ? I mean "date" in part-00001 are guarantee to be superior than thoses in part-00000 ?
3. If not, could you please post a code that meet both requirements explained ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will do `.coalesce(1)` before saving the order will remain.

You can add column with index of order, maybe it will help you.

```scala
myDataframe
  .withColumn("order", row_number().over(Window.orderBy('date)))
  .write
  .csv(...)
```

Comment: Good answer. However could you please elaborate a bit more ? If I do coalesce it will reduce the output to only one file, and I prefer avoid to drop parallelism to 1. Moreover I don't clearly see the point with the "order" column. My goal is to have multiples files output, with sort on "date" column, both inside each file, and between files (part-0000 have "date" inferior to part-0001). What can I then do with the "order" column in order to have sorted files like I need ? Thanks!

Comment: Use coalesce(n) , where n is number of part files you need. this will end up having a global sorting. You god use repartiton(col,n) where col will be your ordering column and n is number of part files , but here you will not get a global sort but each partition would be sorted by within itself.

Comment: So if I do : myDataframe.orderBy("date").coalesce(10).write.csv(...); I will then have both global sorting with 10 files (part-0000 have "date" inferior to part-0001, etc.), AND sort inside each file ? Could you confirm that ?